# change the font of a label of a view through picker

Tags: javascript, titanium-mobile

I want to change the font of a label of a view (from a collection of fonts downloaded in my font folder)through picker added in a modal window.Kindly help. I have tried everything I can. Thanking you in anticipation.

This is what I'm trying to do by setting the app property in picker's eventListener and getting it in fontFamily of label

```
var fontie;

     picker.addEventListener('change', function(e)
   {  
      if(e.rowIndex == 0)
       {

      var fontLabelMain ='Parisish';
      Ti.App.Properties.setString('fontie','fontLabelMain');

       }


var labelMain = Ti.UI.createLabel
({
    text: labelMainValue,
    height : '25%',
    width : 'auto',
    top : '30%',color:'#FFF',
    left : '15%',right:'10%',
    font{fontSize:100,fontFamily:Ti.App.Properties.getString('fontie')},

 });
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You will get much better answers to your questions if you put a bit more effort into them. You say, "I have tried everything I can," but if you show us what those code snippets are, perhaps someone can think of an approach you may have overlooked, or can find an overlooked error. As it stands, there is really no way to answer this question.

Comment: This is what I'm trying to do by setting the app property in picker's eventListener and getting it in fontFamily of label 
var fontie;
  
     picker.addEventListener('change', function(e)
   {  
      if(e.rowIndex == 0)
       {
           var fontLabelMain ='Parisish';
     Ti.App.Properties.setString('fontie','fontLabelMain');
   }

var labelMain = Ti.UI.createLabel
({
  text: labelMainValue,
  height : '25%',
 width : 'auto',
 top : '30%',color:'#FFF',
 left : '15%',right:'10%',//zIndex: 1,
 font: {fontSize:100, fontFamily:Ti.App.Properties.getString('fontie')},minimumFontSize:20,
 });

Answer (score 1):

Here...

```
$('select').on('change', function(){
$('textarea').css('font-family', $(this).val());
//$('input[type="text"]').css('font-family', $(this).val());
```

});

Comment: I have never used this 'on change' function kindly guide.

Comment: Try reading the documentation first, then ask for guidance when you encounter something you don't understand. Documentation: [http://api.jQuery.com/on/](http://api.jQuery.com/on/).

Answer (score 0):

```
var labelMain = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    text: labelMainValue,
    height : '25%',
    width : 'auto',
    top : '30%',color:'#FFF',
    left : '15%',right:'10%',
    font{
        fontSize: 100,
        fontFamily: "Parisish"
    },
});

picker.addEventListener('change', function(e){  
   if(e.rowIndex === 0){
        labelMain.setFont({
            fontSize: 100,
            fontFamily: "Parisish"
        });
   }
}
```

If you have any Fonts you can use (n case = n RowIndex):

```
picker.addEventListener('change', function(e){  
   switch(e.rowIndex){
      case 0:
        labelMain.setFont({
            fontSize: 100,
            fontFamily: "Parisish"
        });
        break;
      case 1:
        ...
        break;
      default:
        break;
   }
}
```